# Find last possible page of Flask-SQLAlchemy paginate

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using paginate of sqlalchemy to paginate my query like following but in my front page I want to implement a next button (or a numerical page navigation links like 1,2,3,4..) and when it reaches at the last page I don't want to show user the next button (or know the maximum number of pages available in the page navigation). I would prefer not to use another database query in sqlalchemy. What is the most convenient way achieve this?

I am using following fo pagination:

```
Blog.query.filter(Blog.title.like("%"+query+"%")).paginate(page=start,per_page=size).items
```

One way could be checking if it returns exact number of items of my size or not what I am doing right now, if not it is the last one, but it does not satisfy corner cases where the remainder of all count and size is zero.

Comment: What libraries do you use? SQLAlchemy doesn't even have `paginate` word in its docs.

Comment: OK, I assume you're using this method: http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/?highlight=paginate#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [`Pagination`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/?highlight=paginate#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.Pagination) class docs.

```
query = (Blog.query.filter(Blog.title.like('%'+query+'%'))
                   .paginate(page=start, per_page=size))
```

Then you can use `query.has_prev` and `query.has_next` properties to check if previous or next pages exist.